# Addressing "TypeError: window.deltaUrlToBlobUrl is not a function"

Tags: react-native

I got snagged for a while trying to figure out why when I refreshed my app I'd get stuck on "Building JavaScript bundle... 100%".

I realized there was an error in my remote debugging console: "TypeError: window.deltaUrlToBlobUrl is not a function". After a little digging, I discovered the issue and solution below. Hope it helps someone else out.

Answer (score 2):

Credit for the final solution goes to this blogger and blog post: https://www.jianshu.com/p/1ead6716e09d

The issue is with the remote debugger being hooked up to and expired session. If you turn off remote debugging in the emulator, refresh the app, and turn it back on again, you'll be all set.